# How to display event's views block inside another content type's content section with only events related to that content alone?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, content-type, drupal-taxonomy

I am working on a drupal7 site. The scenario is that, there are 2 content types namely singers and events. When i am adding an event, i need to add an event to a singer, so that when i am viewing a singer's node page, i can see  block containing events related to that singer alone.

I have done the events block inside the singer's content page(Using the views block). But it displays all the events and i want to display the only the events related to that singer alone. I have tried to make it using term reference or some other stuff. But nothing have worked out. Can anyone help me out to get this scenario working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to link those two content types using [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30011903/3607039), where I have just explained how to do so to another user.

I assume your block is being shown as a view from [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). However, up to now you have not been able to filter the results by singer. Once you have properly linked both content types, you will have to edit your view and add a contextual filter. When I first faced this problem, I used [this guide](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/contextual-filter-with-a-block-view) to solve my problem. Basically you filter the Event list to show only those whose "Singer" id is the *n-th* parameter in the URL (node/**nid**).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried the method you have mentioned. i have linked the content types using the entity reference. But i couldn't achieve the event's views block. I have also tried the following link which also refers the same http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/getting-started-references-drupal . But i need the events views block displaying events. can you help me out in bringing this.

Comment: Could you please edit your question adding a screenshot of your view configuration? A picture of the contextual filter used would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, why term reference when you have 2 content types? Inside your singer content type add node reference to event content type. The same thing as term reference, but obviously, you have to reference a node, not a term.

Second, in your view you must have the  contextual filter that takes singer id.

Third, I'm not sure can that work with block display, but I'm sure it works with embedding view, so my suggestion is to created view display of "embed" type and to embed it directly into singer content type template. This way you can pass singer id (you have it available there: `$node->nid`) parameter easily.